# InputMismatchException when reading from a file using Scanner in Java

Tags: java

I need help with this program for school. I've been getting this error for a few days now and don't know where the problem is. I'm reading information from a file, and for some reason i'm getting the following error:

ok, so I keep getting the following error in my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at EmployeeWithFiles.readInputFile(EmployeeWithFiles.java:22)
    at CompanyWithFilesDemo.main(CompanyWithFilesDemo.java:28)
```

I know the error is in the readInputFile...here's my method to read input:

```
public void readInputFile(Scanner inputStream)
{
        setFirstName(inputStream.nextLine());
        setLastName(inputStream.nextLine());
        setNumberOfDependents(inputStream.nextInt());
        setHourlyRate(inputStream.nextDouble());
        setHoursWorked(inputStream.nextDouble());
        setLocalTaxWithheldToDate(inputStream.nextDouble());
        setFederalTaxWithheldToDate(inputStream.nextDouble());
        setStateTaxWithheldToDate(inputStream.nextDouble());
```

}

And here's my input file:

```
jim
jackson
3
14.50
55.50
515.00
6010.00
2163.00
jim
jackson
3
14.50
55.50
515.00
6010.00
2163.00
jim
jackson
3
14.50
55.50
515.00
6010.00
2163.00
```

Comment: Provide full code.Just check whether the data type of the input parameters passing in the method matches with the arguments defined in the method.I can't find any issue with the scanner class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm almost positive the problem is occurring from one of the `nextInt` or `nextDouble` not carrying to the next line. So at some point you may be trying to read a double when it's a string or vice versa. That's where the `InputMismatchException` occurs.

You can avoid this problem by just reading line by line and parsing when necessary. Make life easier.

```
setNumberOfDependents(Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine().trim()));
setHourlyRate(Double.parseDouble(inputStream.nextLine().trim()));
...
```